# Delphi THandleStream seek bug

Tags: delphi

I spent hours on this, and when I discovered the solution, I was about to fall from my chair...

I'm reading a 6Gb AVI file uncompressed.

Using this variable to handle the file, in Delphi 10.4:

```
VideoFile:THandleStream; 
...
VideoFile := THandleStream.Create(FileHandle);
```

I realized when going from seeks below `0x7FFFFFFF` was OK, but above was not OK.

When I looked to the declarations, `Offset` is an `Int64`, OK:

```
function THandleStream.Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64;
begin
  Result := FileSeek(FHandle, Offset, Ord(Origin));
end;
```

Then `FileSeek()` goes here with ... a 32-bit signed integer... That I did not go into at first glance. What a mistake!

```
function FileSeek(Handle: THandle; Offset, Origin: Integer): Integer;
begin
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Result := SetFilePointer(Handle, Offset, nil, Origin);
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
  Result := lseek(Handle, Offset, Origin);
{$ENDIF POSIX}
end;
```

This is really nasty and very very bad... Why did Embarcadero choose this misleading implementation?

I have used `VideoFile.Position := XXXX` to overcome the issue. But why leave `Int64` in `THandleStream.Seek()`?

Comment: Your diagnosis is not how `THandleStream` really works. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73494751/65863) for details. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating in action the actual problem you are really having. Unless Embarcadero has introduced a regression, the real culprit is more likely to be in your own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your diagnosis is incorrect.

There are two versions of `FileSeek()` - a 32bit version, and a 64bit version:

```
function FileSeek(Handle: THandle; Offset, Origin: Integer): Integer;
begin
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Result := SetFilePointer(Handle, Offset, nil, Origin);
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
  Result := lseek(Handle, Offset, Origin);
{$ENDIF POSIX}
end;

function FileSeek(Handle: THandle; const Offset: Int64; Origin: Integer): Int64;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
begin
  Result := Offset;
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := SetFilePointer(Handle, Int64Rec(Result).Lo,
    @Int64Rec(Result).Hi, Origin);
  if (Int64Rec(Result).Lo = $FFFFFFFF) and (GetLastError <> 0) then
    Int64Rec(Result).Hi := $FFFFFFFF;
end;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
begin
  Result := lseek(Handle, Offset, Origin);
end;
{$ENDIF POSIX}
```

You are looking only at the 32bit version of `FileSeek()`, but `THandleStream` overrides the 64bit version of `TStream.Seek()` to call the 64bit version of `FileSeek()` instead.

`THandleStream.Seek()` is passing a `THandle`, an `Int64`, and a `Byte` to `FileSeek()`, so which version do you think is going to be called?  The 64bit version.  The compiler can upsize a `Byte` to an `Integer` in both cases, but it is not going to downsize an `Int64` to an `Integer` when it can pass the `Int64` as-is instead.  So the 64bit version of `FileSeek()` is a better match for what `THandleStream.Seek()` is passing.

If that were not the case, then your claim that:

> I have used `VideoFile.Position := XXXX` to overcome the issue.

would not be true, since the `TStream.Position` setter method simply calls the same 64bit `Seek()` method that you are claiming to be having trouble with:

```
procedure TStream.SetPosition(const Pos: Int64);
begin
  Seek(Pos, soBeginning); // <-- soBeginning is from TSeekOrigin
end;
```

So, whatever trouble you are actually having, it is not due to the 64bit `THandleStream.Seek()` calling the 32bit `FileSeek()`. That is simply not how `THandleStream` works.

Comment: To reply to Remy

 so which version do you think is going to be called?

I did this ->>

VideoFile.seek(DataInAVI.Offset64,soFromBeginning);

DatainAVI.Offset64 is int64 and when I trace the code it uses the 32 bits version of fileseek, and this causes the bug that I can see. I do not understand why the compiler did a bad "route".

Comment: @AlcorPrism To call the 64bit ‘Seek()’, you need to use the newer ‘TSeekOrigin.soBeginning’ enum value instead of the older ‘soFromBeginning’ constant.

Comment: Remy, you are so good... thanks !